# Cell type of an Excel sheet is shown as Numeric which is actually a Text Type

Tags: excel, apache, parsing, apache-poi

I am using apache-poi-3.9, to process Excel documents.
I have a cell in the document of type TEXT(the cell value is 445). But when I check that cell type in Java it shows NUMERIC. Is there a way to get the cell type as what is there in the excel document.
Note : The cell is defined as TEXT. It may contain alphanumeric values or numeric values but I need that type as Text.

Comment: Excel's cell type depends on the content. If at first numeric content was inputted in a cell and then the cell was formatted as text, then the cell type don't change. The cell type will be string, if at first the cell was formatted as text and then any content (numeric or text)  was inputted in that cell.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the cell type as string:

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

or to set the number format as text:

```
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Check the following links for more details:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Working+with+different+types+of+cells
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats

To extract a formatted value from a cell, after using previous code:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String formatted_value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```

Comment: This is my row object contains:                                                            <main:c r="B2" s="4">
    <main:v>445</main:v>
  </main:c>                                                                                         when I try to get row.getCell(0) it returns 445.0 But I need it as 445

Comment: can you set the number format for the cells in MS Excel?

Comment: The number format is set. There is a style as you see by the attribute `s="4"` in XML `c`  tag. I suspect the style 4 is already number format @ (Text). But the type has not changed as you see by the lacking attribute `t="s"`. The type will changing only if the value is retyped after setting the text number format. But surely you are right with the hint to using `DataFormatter`.